# Springboot application fails to start because of TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm writing a multi module project here is the structure:

Parent: traitementCertificats
Children modules are: 
1- Batch
2- businessLayer

The **Batch** module calls different classes declared in the **businessLayer**.
Here's the Batch module pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>fr.lcl.traitementCertificats</groupId>
    <artifactId>traitementCertificats</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>fr.lcl.traitementcertificats</groupId>
<artifactId>batch</artifactId>
<name>batch</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Jasper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.lcl.traitementCertificats</groupId>
        <artifactId>businessLayer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The maven install command gives a successfull build with the three projects, but when i try to run the Batch module as follow: spring-boot:run

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.Batch.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
    Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type fr.lcl.businessLayer.model.Certificat not present
            at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:320) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:140) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1383) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1284) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1250) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1193) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:164) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:153) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:203) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:115) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.lcl.businessLayer.model.Certificat
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            ... 51 common frames omitted

     2018-07-26 13:37:49.418  INFO 17436 --- [           main] 
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@ca769d2: startup date [Thu Jul 26 13:37:48 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
     2018-07-26 13:37:49.420  WARN 17436 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type fr.lcl.businessLayer.model.Certificat not present
            at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:320) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:140) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1383) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1284) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1250) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1193) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:889) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:875) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at org.Batch.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.lcl.businessLayer.model.Certificat
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
            ... 37 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
            at org.Batch.Application.main(Application.java:10)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type fr.lcl.businessLayer.model.Certificat not present
            at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
            at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
            at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
            at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
            at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)
            at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:419)
            at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:320)
            at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:140)
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1383)
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1284)
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1250)
            at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:788)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:164)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:153)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:203)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:115)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
            ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.lcl.businessLayer.model.Certificat
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
            at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
            ... 51 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.698 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-26T13:37:49+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/385M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project batch: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Type fr.lcl.businessLayer.model.Certificat not present -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**I find it illogic to get this error because there's no compilation errors were detected with Eclipse and the maven install commandline works fine on the project.**

I tried to clean the project rebuild it but the problem persists